# badges.badge dart error "try moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, android-webview

```
 child: badges.Badge(
                              showBadge: false,
                              badges.BadgeColor: white, **"Erros line"**
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                              position:
                                  Badges.badgePosition.topStart(top: 16, start: 9),
                              badges.BadgeContent: const Text(
                                '3',
                                style: TextStyle(color: red, fontSize: 10),
                              )
```

**erros :**
1- Positional arguments must occur before named arguments.\nTry moving all of the positional arguments before the named arguments.
2- Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.\nTry removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.
3- BadgeColor' is being referenced through the prefix 'badges', but it isn't defined in any of the libraries imported using that prefix.\nTry correcting the prefix or importing the library that defines
4- Expected to find ')'.

i faced error with badges befor to i used badges.badge now i faced many error while editting webview app template .

Answer (score 0):

`badges.BadgeContent:` must be `badgeContent:`.

And it seems you need a full style instead of `badges.BadgeColor: white,`:

```
badgeStyle: badges.BadgeStyle(
    badgeColor: Colors.white,
),
```

Generally speaking, it might be worth going back to the drawing board and looking at the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/badges/example) of the package you are using.